# Why do I need a Handler object in this example?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

```
public class ProgressBarTest extends Activity {

    private int progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        progress = 0;
        final ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progress < 10) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    progress++;
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Why can't I just put the pb.setVisibility(View.GONE) in the first Runnable inner class? Like this: The program crashes if I write it this way.

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (progress < 10) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    progress++;
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
```

The program crashes when the setVisibility statement is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot update ui from a thread. Ui should be updated on the ui thread.

In the second one you are setting the visibility of progressbar inside the threads runs method. Hence it crashes. So you use handler to set the visibility of progress bar in the the first

To know more about handlers.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: So if I want to update the UI from a Thread other than the UI Thread, I should always use a handler? Is this the common way how it is done? Because it seems a little bit strange to me. Thx.

Comment: @nomnom that's one way do it using handler. But you cannot update ui from a thread. You can use asynctask. You can use `runOnuiThread` inside the thread run method to update ui. `runOnUiThread` is a method of activity http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable). do check this https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: just to make things clear, the handler just adds a message to the message queue of the thread its associated to, in this case the UI thread, so when you post the update using the handler you are basically posting a message to the queue in the UI handler. If you try and use the approach you suggested you would actually be trying to update UI from a non UI thread